# Session put does not seem to be working properly

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.8, laravel-session

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to make sure that users can submit a form only every 2 hours (as long as a session is alive).

So I tried this at the Controller:

```
if(Session::has('request_has_been_sent')){
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'You just submitted a request and cannot submit a new one');
}else{
    $withDraw = WithdrawWallet::create([
        'balance_value' => $request->balance_wallet,
        'can_draw' => $request->can_draw,
        'shaba_number' => $request->shaba_number,
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name' => $request->last_name,
        'description' => $request->desc,
        'status' => 'pending',
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
    ]);
    Session::put('request_has_been_sent');
}

return redirect()->back()->with('success','Your request was sent');
```

So by this, everytime a user submits a new request, session `request_has_been_sent` must be set.

Therefore at the next time user submits the form, if the session was still alive, the message *`You just submitted a request and cannot submit a new one`* appears.

But now the problem is it does not work. In fact user can still submit another request, right after submitting a request.

This means that the session is not set somehow.

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly do this?

Comment: where you expire this session?

Comment: @Milad It should expired itself after 2 hours. I want this session to be forgotten automatically.

Comment: did you set timer on config/session.php file?

Comment: @Milad It is set to `'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),` at config/session.php

Comment: if you did any change in config file try `php artisan optimize` to reload the cache

Comment: @Milad I didn't change anything, it was in default settings. And the main question here is that the session is not initialized at all!

Comment: ok, did you try to add session with value as I see you dont have any value Ex: `Session::put('Hi', '1')` and then `Session::has('Hi')`

Comment: @Milad Thanks it showed the message but does not prevent user from creating a new record. A new record was added again to the DB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set session using `set` and `put` method

```
Session::put('name','value');
```

Retrieve it using get

```
Session::get('name')
```

So in your case you need to set your session use

```
Session::put('request_has_been_sent','yes');
```

And to check if it is set or not use

```
if(Session::get('request_has_been_sent')){
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session

Comment: It is surprisingly that `Session::has()` does not work for checking session in this case !!

Comment: @nagidi Session::has() checks if the session is set before without any value also it will return true if it is set. but using Session::get() will retrieve value of session. so if it doesnt have any value then it will return false. In your case you need to make sure to remove value from session `request_has_been_sent` after 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problem here is not setting the session value to anything you need to set it to something or else laravel will ignore it.

```
Session::put('request_has_been_sent', true);

// Check if it exists, this will check if it exists without getting it
Session::has('request_has_been_sent')
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the user is logged out al the user sesion wil be flushd out. Which means user and create and `WithdrawWallet` and logout and then login again and then user can create another `WithdrawWallet` so to fix that you can use cache

```
$cacheKey = WithdrawWallet::class.'.'.auth()->user()->usr_id;

    if (Cache::has($cacheKey)) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'You just submitted a request and cannot submit a new one');
    } else {
        $withDraw =  Cache::remember($cacheKey, now()->addHours(2), function () use ($request){
            return  WithdrawWallet::create([
                'balance_value' => $request->balance_wallet,
                'can_draw' => $request->can_draw,
                'shaba_number' => $request->shaba_number,
                'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                'last_name' => $request->last_name,
                'description' => $request->desc,
                'status' => 'pending',
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
            ]);
        });
    
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Your request was sent');
```